# How to use list to force IndexError?

Tags: python, list, nodes

Suppose I have a matrix like list `map`, where I am storing some objects. Now as per as how list works, `map[x-1]` yields in `map[elemInList-1]`. Apart from manually setting boundaries of x like if `x < 0`, is there any other workaround?

This is what I was trying

```
for x in range(row):
    for y in range(col):
        try:
            print "trying left", map[x][y - 1]
            map[x][y].neighbors.append(map[x][y - 1])
        except IndexError:
            pass
```

Example:

```
a b c d e
f g h i j
k l m n o
```

What I'm trying to do is, map the neighboring elements from each position. So for each positions, I'm trying to add left, right, up and down positions.Now suppose I'm at `[1][0]`(F) and trying to check if anything exists for its left. [1][0 - 1] would point to j, which is not what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Just a note: you should use `map` as variable name because you are shadowing the built-in [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function.

Comment: I honestly cannot understand what it is you're trying to do. Try and make your point a bit more clear and offer an example which people here can use.

Comment: @Jim. clarification added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking to do?

```
grid = [list('abcde'), list('fghij'), list('klmno')]
print grid

neigh = [(-1,0), (0,-1), (1,0), (0,1)]
nrows, ncols = 3, 5
for i in range(nrows):
    for j in range(ncols):
        print 'neighbours of', grid[i][j], ':',
        for (dj, di) in neigh:
            ni, nj = i + di, j + dj
            if not (0 <= ni < nrows and 0 <= nj < ncols):
                continue
            print grid[ni][nj],
        print

neighbours of a : b f
neighbours of b : a c g
neighbours of c : b d h
neighbours of d : c e i
neighbours of e : d j
neighbours of f : a g k
neighbours of g : f b h l
neighbours of h : g c i m
neighbours of i : h d j n
neighbours of j : i e o
neighbours of k : f l
neighbours of l : k g m
neighbours of m : l h n
neighbours of n : m i o
neighbours of o : n j
```

Comment: I was wondering if there was any way avoid the `if not` conditionals (as in some built in python mechanism or sth). But your answer helped me to see a very neat way to do it :)

Comment: @Roy - glad it helped! You might want to add your own solution as an answer as well.